# java switch-case don't open a jfilechooser window

Tags: java, user-interface, switch-statement, case, jfilechooser

As I searched already topics about it thru internet and here, I would try to ask.

In the codepart below I tried to open a JFileChooser, with the switch case, but it doesn't.

Without the switch case construct it open the window and works.

```
switch(choose) {
case 1:
 new testFc().openFchooser();
 //System.out.println("ok");
break;


public void openFchooser() {
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
System.out.println(returnVal);
System.out.println("ok");
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
 try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath())) {
  this.t = inputFile.next();
  System.out.println(t);
 }
}
}
```

Comment: what's the value of choose? How hard is it to debug this  line by line?

Comment: in your code the switch is closed after the other method or never close...(Check that)

Comment: Thank you for your answers and help.                                                         I found the problem, which seemed to solve it.                                                                              The JFileChooser shoudn't be open in the Switch-case, I shifted and inizialed it out of the method.     I should read more about how to use the debugger in the IDE.

Comment: Sorry I meant the line JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();     , is writed out of the method. But I don't know exactly why.